# Do I put code Android in-app billing sample(Trival drive) to perform?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-studio-import

I don't understand this sentence.

**"Add the helper classes from the /util directory of the TrivialDrive sample to your project. Remember to change the package name declarations in those files accordingly so that your project compiles correctly."**

It's from here:

https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

And I want to put util code to my app, but how?

File > New > Import Sample?

or

File > New > Import Project?

or just copy and paste it?

Comment: From what I understand, there is no importing involved, you simply copy those classes (the `.java` files) to your project and change their package name to the package you're copied them to.

Comment: Thanks Titus. But Just copied that code to my project, error comes out. cannot resolve .getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus() method.